# nltk.downloader gives xml.etree.ElementsTree.ParseError

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am trying to build a docker image. While executing the given command:

`RUN python -m nltk.downloader punkt`

The build fails by throwing the below error:

`nltk.downloader gives xml.etree.ElementsTree.ParseError : unclosed token: line 108, column 4`

nltk version used: `3.4.5`. Also tried with 3.5.0

Python: 3.5 is used

What is causing this ?

Comment: That sounds like you should open an issue. https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues

Comment: @polm23 I remember it was working last week.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the specific version of `ntlk` you are using.

---

Try to upgrade to a newer version and try again:

```
pip install nltk --upgrade
```

Comment: I have tried by specifying and without specifying the version in the requirements file.

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi Try to install version `3.5.0`

Comment: Tried to install with nltk 3.5.0, it didn't do any help.